# Monitor flickering ATI

Tags: drivers, ati, multiple-monitors, fglrx

I'm using ubuntu 12.10 on laptop samsung with randeon hd 6620g (APU A8), when I run amdcccle -version it says 2.18, not sure if that's the correct version.

My problem is that I have and external monitor, AOC e2343Fsk and when I finally got it working at the resolution I want 1920x1080 it works fine for like 5minutes and then it starts flickering... I solved this on Windows (the exact same problem) with some options (I don't remember very well) I believe there were some buttons '+' and '-' on some vsync option I played with them on windows and Yay! got it working, but I don't see anything similar on this catalyst version (I used xorg-edgers ppa for installing fglrx).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Run Ubuntu Software Center
2. Install CompizConfig Settings Manager
3. Run CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm)
4. Click OpenGL
5. Ensure Vertex Buffer Object is unchecked